Знаки препинания и кавычки
Следует ли данные случаи оформлять как прямую речь, писать с заглавной и ставить в конце точку:

Его клич можно расшифровать как «Помогите!».


Он расшифровал её клич как «Помогите!», хотя это было лишь «Что?».

Нашёл следующие правила:

Кавычками подчеркивается чисто грамматическая необычность употребления слов, например в случае, когда в качестве членов предложения употребляются части речи или целые обороты, не предназначенные для выражения данных функций: «Хочешь?» , «давай ты» звучало в моих ушах и производило какое-то опьянение; я ничего и никого не видел, кроме Сонечки (Л. Т.); От его приветливого «я вас ждал» она повеселела (Б. П.).


Примечание 1. Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит знак
вопросительный, или восклицательный, или многоточие, то те же самые
знаки не повторяются после кавычек; неодинаковые же знаки, если они
требуются в силу характера соответствующих частей текста, могут
ставиться перед закрывающими кавычками и после них, например:
Читали ли вы роман Чернышевского «Что делать?»
Но:
Драматический кружок готовит к постановке пьесу «В бой!». Отчего вы
говорите: «Как бы не так!»?


Скажите, почему не принят ответ и нет ваших комментариев? Что-нибудь непонятно, а то я дополнительно могу пояснить.

Нет, всё понятно, спасибо. Подумал, что если принять ответ сразу, то обсуждение фактически закроется, если тут это так работает, конечно.

Краткая теория

Есть разные способы оформления дословного высказывания: классическая прямая речь и другие варианты, в том числе встроенная  (упрощенная) прямая речь.

В классическом варианте прописная буква, двоеточие, кавычки, а в конце нужный знак (точка после кавычек, восклицательный или вопросительный знаки до кавычек). В этом случае конструкция состоит из двух самостоятельных частей: слова автора и прямая речь персонажа.

Встроенная прямя речь входит в состав предложения, поэтому собственного знака на конце этого предложения после кавычек не имеет.


Такое прямое высказывание оформляется по-разному в зависимости от распространенности и желания автора: прописная или строчная буква, собственный восклицательный или вопросительный знак перед кавычками.
На конце предложения стоит знак этого предложения: запятая внутри предложения; точка, восклицательный или вопросительный знак  в конце.
 Его клич можно расшифровать как «Помогите!». Он расшифровал 
 её клич как «Помогите!», хотя это было лишь «Что?».


Вопросительный знак не повторяется при вопросительном характере предложения:
Читали ли вы роман Чернышевского «Что делать?» 



В остальных случаях два знака:
 Драматический кружок готовит к постановке пьесу «В бой!». 
 Отчего вы говорите: «Как бы не так!»?

